# Find value in list of dicts and return id of dict

Tags: python

I'd like to try and find if a value is in a list of dicts, which can be done easily with:

```
if any(x['aKey'] == 'aValue' for x in my_list_of_dicts):
```

But this is only a boolean response, I'd like to not only check if the value is there, but to also access it afterwards, so something like:

```
for i, dictionary in enumerate(my_list_of_dicts):
    if dictionary['aKey'] == 'aValue':
        # Then do some stuff to that dictionary here
        # my_list_of_dicts[i]['aNewKey'] = 'aNewValue'
```

Is there a better/more pythonic way of writing this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function, if expected to find only one *target* dict:

```
my_list_of_dicts = [{'aKey': 1}, {'aKey': 'aValue'}]
target_dict = next((d for d in my_list_of_dicts if d['aKey'] == 'aValue'), None)
if target_dict: target_dict['aKey'] = 'new_value'

print(my_list_of_dicts)
```

The output (input list with updated dictionary):

```
[{'aKey': 1}, {'aKey': 'new_value'}]
```

Comment: @AGH_TORN, let's use `next`'s default value in that case, see my update

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension.  This will return a list of dictionaries that match your condition.

```
[x for x in my_list_of_dicts if x['aKey']=='aValue' ]
```